# She looked as if / as though she had known everything

Tags: grammar

Do all these sentences refer to unreal situation? Are they grammatically correct?

Can we use 'past perfect' in this structure?

> He **seemed** as if he **hadn't slept** for days.
>
> He **looked** as if he **knew** the answer.
>
> She **looked** as if / as though she **had known** everything.
>
> He **seems** as if **he hadn't slept** for days.
>
> Peter was extremely hungry and ate his dinner very quickly. He **ate**
>   as if he **hadn't eaten** for a week.

The following explanation from Michael Swan book makes me confused:

> Note that we do not use a past perfect for a past unreal comparison.
>   She **looked as if she was rich,** but she wasn’t. (NOT --- as if she had been rich.)

Comment: As if=like and means resemblance in some cases or dreaming. His nose looked as if it were broken - It resembled a broken nose, we can't know for sure whether it was broken or was not.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/as-if-and-as-though

Answer (score 1):

"He seemed as if he hadn't slept for days" should be either "It seemed…" or "He looked…"

"He looked as if he knew the answer" would be better as "It looked…"

"She looked as if / as though she had known everything" should be "It looked…"

"He seems as if he hadn't slept for days" should be "It seemed…" or "He looked…"

"Peter was extremely hungry and ate his dinner very quickly. He ate as if he hadn't eaten for a week" is grammatically acceptable but "ate / eaten" isn't a great choice.

"He ate as if he hadn't fed for a week" would beat "ate / eaten"

"He gobbled his food as if he hadn't eaten for a week" would beat "ate / eaten"

"He fed as if he hadn't eaten for a week" would beat "ate / eaten"

(Unless of course, you're Clive Cussler, who uses forms like "ate / eaten" and even "eat / eaten" on most pages and is still one of the most successful authors ever…)